Can't install php8.2-curl
apt install php8.2-curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php8.2-curl
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.2-curl'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php8.2-curl'

Then tried:
apt install php-curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php-curl : Depends: php7.2-curl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Any Thoughts?

Does this answer your question? Unable to install php8.2-dev on ubuntu 20.04 (sudo apt install php8.2-curl)

What Ubuntu version are you using?
